# Starting state out of bounds for a real UR robot

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, universal-robot, universal-robots, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with a real UR5e robot and I can see the current robot pose and its update when it's moved manualy in moveit.
However, I am not able to plan, because it's always Failed result, due to:

```
You can start planning now!

[ INFO] [1570454211.959254809]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[ WARN] [1570454211.959419965]: Joint 'wrist_1_joint' from the starting state is outside bounds
```

And other errors follow. Why I am representing the real robot pose properly but I've got this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334784/starting-state-out-of-bounds-for-a-real-ur-robot/) by [UR5e](https://answers.ros.org/users/46501/ur5e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Why I am representing the real robot pose properly but I've got this error?

Because rendering current state (RViz) is completely disconnected from being able to plan new motions for your robot (MoveIt).

If you have the option: don't run the join-limited versions of the `.launch` files *or* make sure your robot is not outside the plannable range for each of its joints.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UR5e](https://answers.ros.org/users/46501/ur5e/) on 2019-10-08**:
Thank you, Now the planning is performed successfuly. However, when I Execute it, remains as:

[ INFO] Path simplification took 0.095551 seconds and changed from 3 to 2 states

[ INFO] Received new trajectory execution service request...

And robot doesn't move. I am missing anything? Thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-08**:
That would seem to be a different problem. Please don't post follow-up questions in comments under answers.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-08**:
Also: you appear to be cross-posting this to [ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver#354](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/issues/354) and [ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver#339](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver/pull/339#issuecomment-539468159). Please don't do that, it's not very nice.